# What removeable dashboard cameras befit car renters?

Tags: car-rentals

My grandparents rent cars whenever they travel to other Canadian provinces for roadtripping. They need a [dashboard camera](http://www.autofocus.ca/how-to/knowledge-base/everything-you-need-to-know-about-using-a-dash-cam-in-canada), as someone tried to defraud one of her friends like [the following](https://www.smrlaw.ca/Articles/Dashcams-can-help-but-also-hurt-in-an-insurance-dispute.shtml):

> As [CBC News reports](https://www.smrlaw.ca/Articles/Dashcams-can-help-but-also-hurt-in-an-insurance-dispute.shtml), in at least one instance  a driver's dashcam may have saved him from falling victim to insurance fraud. In that case the dashcam recorded the man's vehicle being struck, seemingly deliberately, by another vehicle. While it was impossible to say for sure in that case whether the crash was an attempt at insurance fraud, industry experts say dashcams are proving useful at protecting safe drivers against unscrupulous or dangerous motorists.

[This Reddit post is 1 year old](https://redd.it/4nz4tt), and [this 3 years](https://redd.it/33b0y3).

Comment: Almost every single dash camera on the market is easily removable. Can you clarify why the most popular models don't fit your parents? Otherwise this is too broad.

Comment: @JonathanReez "Almost every single dash camera on the market is easily removable." How can they check this, before they buy one?

Comment: ... by checking reviews?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more about car accessories than about travel.